# How to synchronize product inventory stock in 2 databases. Mysql and MSSQL real time

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, magento, synchronize

i have Magento e-commerce system with Mysql and windows based POS system written .net with MSSQL Database,

what's the best way to manage the stock in real time ?

Solution 1
to write a cron job to export transaction to xml file then send the data, also to read the update data from the POS via ftp.
and on the POS system to create widows server to read the xml file to update database and after export xml to update Magento when ever there is sales or manually changes into the stock.

Solution 2
can i create a web service to update stock on both ends?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A typical approach would be to queue your updates in a messaging system that delivers to both RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Real time is almost always a tricky beast to tackle.

What I would do is utilize the Magento API to get and set the information you need regarding the stock. You may find that the Magento API is a little slow. Alan Storm has some good articles explaining the ins and outs of the API at his blog at alanstorm.com. I would look there if you want to know more.

Alan Storm also has released his own API called MercuryAPI. This could possibly help you.

Otherwise you could just create your own API endpoints for what you need to handle. I have found that sometimes this is your best bet. The one thing you have to remember is that you alone are going to be responsible for securing anything you make on your own (just be careful). In your case, you probably will be dealing with the Stock Item models of Magento. You don't necessarily need to handle the entire product model to just update stock levels.